# Javascript confirm delete

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Am creating a simple cms and i have the following

```
<input type="submit" value="delete" title="Delete Aricle(s)" id="delete_btn" onclick="delete_confirm()" />

<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
    <input id="article_id"name="article[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $article->id; ?>" /></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo anchor('admin/articles/edit/'.$article->id,$article->title); ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $article->author; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $article->category; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php published($article->post_status); ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php featured($article->featured); ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $article->views; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $article->post_date; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
  </tbody>
```

The above code is wrapped in a form tag

This my javascript code

```
function delete_confirm() {
    var msg = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the selected article(s)');
    if(msg == false) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is delete function in my controller

```
function articles_delete() {
        //Load Model
        $this->load->model("article_model");
        //Assign article id to variable
        $checkbox = $_POST['article'];
        //loop through selected checkbox
        for($i = 0; $i < count($checkbox); $i++) {
            //Call delete method of the article model
            $this->article_model->delete($checkbox[$i]);
        }
        $this->session->set_flashdata("message","Article(s) Deleted");
        redirect("admin/articles","refresh");
     }
```

But when cancel is clicked in the confirm dialog the form still is still  submited and the selected article deleted.
Please advice on what to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing

`<input type="submit" value="delete" title="Delete Aricle(s)" id="delete_btn" onclick="delete_confirm()" />`

to

`<input type="submit" value="delete" title="Delete Aricle(s)" id="delete_btn" onclick="return delete_confirm();" />`

You're running the delete_confirm() function inside of the onclick function. you need to return false from the onclick() function itself.

Answer (score 2):

try `onSubmit` instead of `onClick`.

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return delete_confirm();" ...>
  <input ...>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted via the `type="submit"`-button, your `delete_confirm()`-function is called. If it returns `true`, the form is submitted. If it returns `false`, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Try using AJAX to call the PHP script from within Javascript.

This means set the input button type to button `<input type="button" />` and change the onclick such that if cancel is pressed, return false (like what you did) or if OK is pressed, run the AJAX script and redirect the page if required...

You could write the AJAX server-side (PHP) script in a seperate file, and send in the paramters using $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

`delete_confirm()` must always return `false` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You want the delete confirm function to be your `onsubmit` attribute of the form.  Having it on the input element is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use:

```
<a href="javascript: if(confirm('Relly?')) { document.getElementById('your_form').action='php.php'; document.getElementById('your_form').submit(); } ">Delete</a>
```